# OpenLane .gds file simulation/verification

Tags: pcb-design, integrated-circuit, semiconductor-process-technology

Is there any way/software to simulate a .gds file.
I know this file is only a geometry file so it doesn't really contain any information about the physical connections between stuff, it only seems to be a bunch of rectangles or other polygons in different layers.

It would still be very cool to see a design beign simulated this way though. Similir as the visual6502 simulator.

I'm wondering if there isn't maybe something similar to visual6502 but for any .gds file or maybe even an intermediate file generated by OpenLane?

Answer (score 0):

There is software that will extract a transistor-level netlist from a GDS-II file, but you will need a definition for the manufacturing process first and a lot of money. This is routinely done as part of IC design to verify that the layout matches the original design.